# Как сохранить позицию recyclerView c динамическими данными

Tags: android, recyclerview

Я Использую пример Google [по ссылки](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-RecyclerView/blob/master/kotlinApp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/recyclerview/RecyclerViewFragment.kt) на класс `RecyclerViewFragment` В данном примере используются статические данные

```
private fun initDataset() {
        dataset = Array(DATASET_COUNT, {i -> "This is element # $i"})
}
```

А я к этому примеру подключил данные которые приходят с сервера с задержкой, поэтому  `recyclerView.adapter = CustomAdapter(dataset)` срабатывает раньше времени.

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater,
                              container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_frag,
                container, false).apply { tag = TAG}

        recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)

        // LinearLayoutManager is used here, this will layout the elements in a similar fashion
        // to the way ListView would layout elements. The RecyclerView.LayoutManager defines how
        // elements are laid out.
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)

        currentLayoutManagerType = LayoutManagerType.LINEAR_LAYOUT_MANAGER

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            // Restore saved layout manager type.
            currentLayoutManagerType = savedInstanceState
                    .getSerializable(KEY_LAYOUT_MANAGER) as LayoutManagerType
        }
        setRecyclerViewLayoutManager(currentLayoutManagerType)

        // Set CustomAdapter as the adapter for RecyclerView.
        recyclerView.adapter = CustomAdapter(dataset)

        return rootView
    }
```

Вот что я сделал

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        ...

        mDownloadInformationFromTheServerNews.initWorkingWithData(object : DownloadInformationFromTheServerNews.WorkingWithData{
            override fun getData(list: ArrayList<ArticlesList>) {
                DATASET_COUNT = list.size
                lists.addAll(list)
                positions += 30

                val handler = android.os.Handler()

                handler.postDelayed({
                    remove() /Как только данные пришли, сообщаю адаптеру. 
                }, 2000)
            }
        })
        remove() // Если это не сделаю, старые данные не увижу, которые
                 // отображаются после переворота экрана

        return rootView
    }
```

И вот что получил. Почему так происходит?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как только я перевернул экрана, срабатывает второй вызов метода `remove()` и я вижу ранее сохраненную позицию, но как только вызывается первый `remove()` список возвращается к первой позиции.

**Если убрать** второй вызов `remove()`, тогда я не увижу сохраненную позицию, а буду просто по истечении таймера возвращается к первой позиции.

**А если убрать** первый `remove()` который находиться в таймере, всё будет ок, только вот как то нужно сообщить что данные обновились в массиве. Иначе при первом запуски данные не отобразится, нужно переворачивать телефон.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу вам сказать, что при повороте activity полностью перестраивается. В том числе повторно вызываются все методы: отсюда вы и видите второй remove. Полагаю, что вам нужно тригирить поворот экрана и не делать повторного запроса на сервер (и очистку адаптера), если перестроение вызвано поворотом экрана. Извините, но с реализация я помочь не могу, у меня нет подходящего примера.

Comment: Этот способ работает, когда я при первом запуске сделал запрос к базе данных, а уже после, с помощью флага запрещаю, а при достижении конца списка подгружаю новые и вызываю `recyclerView.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`. Я еще немного подожду с принятием ответа.